# npm install express warn no description no repository no license

Tags: node.js

I try to install express with vs code, but I get 3 npm warn
No description
No repository field
No license
Neither does it load node-modules and json

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfuwB.jpg)

Comment: Please post text as text, not as links to pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

On vs code use terminal
then your target folder write `npm init`
then select entry point `index.js`
after that type `npm install express --save` press enter

For more go to : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Comment: Kayes Thank you so much

Comment: your welcome keep posting nice question.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing an npm dependency but are not working in a npm package. Try running `npm init` and following the instructions that appear in the terminal.

Read more: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules